# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported - jQuery.post()

Tags: spring-mvc

**Update:** [See here for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29845198/3914412)

Using Spring MVC 4.

Here's my JavaScript code that makes the POST request:

```
$("input.toggleCourse").change(function(e){
    var d = {
        classID: classID,
        courseID: courseID
    };

    $.post(
        "<c:url value="/class/addCourse" />",
        JSON.stringify(d))
    .done(function(data){
        alert("ok");
    });
});
```

(Tried with and without JSON.stringify, tried full $.ajax instead of $.post)

Here's my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/class/addCourse", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addCourse(@RequestBody final CourseInClass cic) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        Class c = classServ.findOne(cic.ClassID);
        c.Courses.add(courseServ.findOne(cic.CourseID));
        sb.append("{success:true}");
    } catch (Exception e){
        sb.append("{error:\"").append(e.getMessage()).append("\"}");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I checked the network log that it sends the correct headers to the correct url. Post requests work for normal forms, but not for this ajax call.

Thanks.

Comment: Spring MVC can be a little confusing for URLs. A full URL is split as  : `http://host/contextPath/dispatcherServletPath/controllerPath`. I think that `curl` only adds context path. So if dispatcherServlet is not mapped to `/` or `/*` browser will not hit the correct controller.

Answer (score 1):

How do you think (String classID, String courseID) will be detected by Spring. i.e. how will the json object be mapped to java object.

If you want to use auto binding you can use jackson-mapper-asl. Take a look at this [page](https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/)

If you don't want to use it you can use @PathVariable, 
change method signatures to `public @ResponseBody String addCourse(@PathVariable String classID, @PathVariable String courseID) {..}`

and then hit `http://localhost:8080/<appname>/class/addCourse/<classID>/<courseID>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated with jackson (original code updated) but still the same error.

Comment: Also tried the other solution with @PathVariables, same error