# The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (jquery POST to spring)

Tags: spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC 4.

Here's my jQuery POST call:

```
$.post("<c:url value="/class/addCourse" />/" + d.classID + "/" + d.courseID);
```

Here's my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/class/addCourse/{classID}/{courseID}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addCourse(@PathVariable String classID, @PathVariable String courseID) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        Class c = classServ.findOne(classID);
        c.Courses.add(courseServ.findOne(Long.parseLong(courseID)));
        sb.append("{success:true}");
    } catch (Exception e){
        sb.append("{error:\"").append(e.getMessage()).append("\"}");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Here's the error

[image]

Here are the headers for the request

[image]

Comment: what is the url in browser?

Comment: @vivekpansara I have updated with a screenshot of the headers including urls.

Comment: Have you tried this : `$.post("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/class/addCourse/" + d.classID + "/" + d.courseID);`

Comment: Same error, but code looks prettier.

Comment: can you post your form?

Comment: You should try to control what is really exchanged between the browser and the server, with a network spy like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark/org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Spring Security, a CSRF token must be included in POST header. A token is automatically generated in a hidden field on the page. This AJAX request works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/class/addCourse/" + d.classID + "/" + d.courseID,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("input[name=_csrf]").val());
    }
});
```